# contenScriptFile : Do we always need jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

This tutorial  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL is showing how to use scripts in order to modify web pages. It is possible to load scripts from another script file using `contentScriptFile`. My question is what would be the content of the `contentScriptFile` ? The tutorial is giving the example of :

```
$("body").html("<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>");
```

But isn't this line using jQuery ? Is it necessary to add jQuery whenever we use `contentScriptFile` ? In this case shouldn't we add jQuery to the add-on directory, as shown in the tutorial :  `contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.7.min.js"), self.data.url("my-script.js")]` ?

Comment: It's using jQuery for the purposes of that example; it's just a hypothetical situation to explain how one would include jQuery, in other words. It's not suggesting anything about whether jQuery is a good idea or not.

Comment: Ok I see, then what should my-script.js contain ? Is the line : document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>"; sufficient ?

Comment: It's just an example; a real script you write should contain whatever code you need in order to get the results you want.

Comment: Ok I understand. But I am new to Firefox SDK and I tried to run the code using separated files, with my-script.js containing document.innerHTML = "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";  but it did not work...

Comment: Just a side note: `document.innerHTML` won't work (no such property on `document`), but `document.body.innerHTML` will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is just a layer on top of the regular DOM/Web APIs. So you don't really need it.

Actually, the first example on that tutorial page gives the same example without jQuery:

```
// Import the page-mod API
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

// Create a page mod
// It will run a script whenever a ".org" URL is loaded
// The script replaces the page contents with a message
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

You can just stuff the `contentScript` into a `contentScriptFile` instead, of course.

So no, you don't need to use jQuery. In fact, and this is my personal opinion, you should probably avoid jQuery if you can, as most of the time the performance hit of loading jQuery in the first place doesn't outweigh the added benefits, in particular since you don't really have to deal with cross-browser incompatibilities, which is one of the major benefits of jQuery.